# Why is my crontab not working?

Tags: linux, unix, cron, rsync

I'm trying to get a cron job to run rsync. I started with this:

```
*/30 * * * * rsync -avz -e "ssh -i /home/ubuntu/ocf_dev_us"  ubuntu@10.0.12.76:/home/ubuntu/kumar/ /home/ubuntu/kumar/"
```

and it wasn't working, so I replaced it with this:

```
0 * * * * env > /tmp/env.output
```

and even that isn't working. How do I find out what's going on?

Comment: It is unclear what you ask. Certainly the crontab will not produce any meaningful action if you comment out the `rsync`. Please try to explain better what exactly _is working_ and what _is not working_.

Comment: Basically i am running ubuntu EC2 instance on aws. I am trying to run command per min by using crontab.I put  * * * * * env > /tmp/env.output in crontab -e .Even this basic command  is not triggering in every 1 min.

Comment: Make sure your cron daemon is up and running, please add your full crontab content to the question and check your system logs for related entries.

Comment: I cleaned up your question based on what you said in the comments, but we still need a little more information. As @arkascha said, please add logs and the full crontab and we can take another look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your cronjob fires only every 60 minutes. Try this

```
* * * * * env > /tmp/env.output
```

to find out if your cronjob is working.